# can't apply gradle application plugin to my build script

Tags: plugins, gradle

my build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'
......
```

when I execute **gradle build** I get the following output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project XXXXX.
**Cause: Plugin with id 'application' not found.**

I'm using gradle-0.9.2. I'v also noticed that the class [ApplicationPlugin](http://gradle.org/1.0-milestone-1/docs/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/ApplicationPlugin.html) does not exist in my GRADLE_HOME/lib/plugin

-- Yonatan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Application Plugin was introduced in Gradle 1.0-milestone-1. Since this was otherwise mostly a bugfix release, upgrading should be safe.